# Write to a file until it reaches a certain size

Tags: perl, file

I am writing an XML file for sitemap and Google says that the file cannot be greater than 10MB.

I was wondering if there is a way to write to a file until a certain file size is met, then close it and open a new one.

I have it so that once it reaches a certain number of entries, it will close file and open a new one.

I was using [`Number::Bytes::Human`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Bytes::Human) to try to get the file size with no luck.

Comment: I'm guessing the sitemap won't work if you stop writing at exactly 10MB...what if the 10MB mark is in the middle of a tag?

Comment: I don't see how `Number::Bytes::Human` will help you. It simply changes the representation of powers of 1024 to a string, which is only really useful when you are building output for human consumption. It won't help you write an algorithm based on file sizes.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought a site map over 10MB was of much use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `tell` method on a file handle to establish the offset where the next data will be written. The method is provided by [`IO::Seekable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Seekable), which is subclassed by [`IO::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::File). Since v5.14 of Perl, `IO::File` is autoloaded on demand, so there is no need to explicitly `use` it

Here's an example program that writes to a file until it exceeds 10MB

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;
use feature 'say';

open my $fh, '>', '10MB.txt';

say $fh->tell;

print $fh '1234567890' while $fh->tell < 10 * 1024 * 1024;

say $fh->tell;

close $fh;
```

#### output

```
0
10485760
```

Note that you you will have to be careful to reassemble the XML data correctly after it has been transmitted, as an XML document must contain exactly one root element